# Finding string array comma-delimited list of strings

Tags: c#, arrays, string

what is the best way to find string array comma delimited list of string and below is my example and I'm getting all the time `false`

```
const string _select_records = ("show all records, show invalid records, show valid records" );

bool flag = _select_records.Split(',').Contains("show all records");
```

Comment: It returns `true`, I can't reproduce it.

Comment: isn't the logic the same without the `Split()` clause?

Comment: why is downvote? care to explain why?

Comment: @Habib: I'm not sure how you are getting true

Comment: Your example evaluates to true.  Perhaps you meant `Contains("show invalid records")` or `Contains("show valid records")`?  Becuase *those* would evaluate to false - they would be missing the leading white-space left behind by the `Split` method.

Comment: @AbuHamzah, check this fiddle. I have copy pasted your code in there https://dotnetfiddle.net/nD3tSo (and not my downvote)

Comment: @Habib: i have changed to a different value within the comma delimited and getting false https://dotnetfiddle.net/I3QH5g

Comment: See my comment on why.

Comment: @AbuHamzah, now that is a separate issue, that is due to leading white space in the split array result for that particular element. Modify your question with this value, otherwise your current question with the current value is not right.

Comment: Change your string assignment to this and your issue should disappear: `const string _select_records = ("show all records,show invalid records,show valid records" );`

Comment: ah oh shoot... i was not thinking of spacing

Comment: Either remove it from the initial value as I've shown, or as @Habib has pointed out in his answer, trim the selections.  His solution has the advantage of avoiding the risk of guessing *how many* leading/trailing white-spaces exist - if for example, you didn't have control over the comma-delimited string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `bool flag = _select_records.Split(',').Contains("show invalid records");` is returning false because the array returned by `Split`  would return three elements, and since the second and third element have space before the delimiter your values in array would be like:

```
"show all records" //no leading space
" show invalid records" // one leading space
" show valid records" // one leading space
```

Now this check `.Contains("show invalid records");` is applied on a string array so it is [`IEnumerable<T>.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) which would look for an array element with exact value as "show invalid records", **without leading space**. Since there is no array element matching the exact value, it returns false.

There could be a number of ways to solve it, simplest would be remove the trailing and leading white spaces with `Trim` and then applying `Contains` like:

```
bool flag = _select_records.Split(',').Select(s=> s.Trim())
                           .Contains("show invalid records");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you ...

```
var stringToCheck = "show all records";
bool flag = _select_records.Split(',').Any(stringToCheck.Contains))
```

What you had should work also.